# Copy Paste Values only( xlPasteValues )

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy entire column in sheetA to Sheet B. sheetA column has values formed with formuls. I'm copying SheetA column values only using *xlPasteValues*. But it is not paste the values to another sheetB. The column in sheetB is empty. 
 My VBA Code

```
    Public Sub CopyrangeA()

    Dim firstrowDB As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim arr1, arr2, i As Integer

    firstrowDB = 1
    arr1 = Array("BJ", "BK")
    arr2 = Array("A", "B")

         For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        With Sheets("SheetA")
           lastrow = Application.Max(3, .Cells(.Rows.Count, arr1(i)).End(xlUp).Row)
           .Range(.Cells(1, arr1(i)), .Cells(lastrow, arr1(i))).Copy
           Sheets("SheetB").Range(arr2(i) & firstrowDB).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to work OK for me. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors. SheetB column is empty

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with the main window alongside? Breaking down the code may help find your error as well. Maybe add some `.Select`'s to it while stepping through to try and pinpoint whats happening, but as there doesnt seem to be anything stopping the code from working as far as I can see after running it myself, theres not much else I can suggest.

Comment: [Using The Transfer Method](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/best-way-to-copy-pastespecial-values-only-with-vba) helped me when I was getting #N/A values on a regular copy paste

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you are wanting to just copy the whole column, you can simplify the code a lot by doing something like this:

```
Sub CopyCol()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy

    Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Or

```
Sub CopyCol()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Copy

    Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("B").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Or if you want to keep the loop

```
Public Sub CopyrangeA()

    Dim firstrowDB As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim arr1, arr2, i As Integer

    firstrowDB = 1
    arr1 = Array("BJ", "BK")
    arr2 = Array("A", "B")

    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)

        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(arr1(i)).Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(arr2(i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd avoid using clipboard for automation whenever possible. If the user or another application uses the clipboard at the same time, the data might end up in unexpected places. This could cause data loss or even a leak of classified information.

Answer (score 18):

since you only want values copied, you can pass the values of `arr1` directly to `arr2` and avoid copy/paste.

code inside the `For` loop, inside the `With` block, after `lastrow` calculation:

```
Sheets("SheetB").Range(arr2(i) & firstrowDB).Resize(lastrow).Value = .Range(arr1(i) & 1).Resize(lastrow).Value
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would shorten it a touch too if all you need is the columns:

```
For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    Sheets("SheetA").Columns(arr1(i)).Copy
    Sheets("SheetB").Columns(arr2(i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next
```

as from this code snippet, there isnt much point in `lastrow` or `firstrowDB`

Answer (score 2):

you may use this:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this too

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Sheet1.Range("A:A").Copy

Sheet2.Activate
col = 1
Do Until Sheet2.Cells(1, col) = ""
    col = col + 1
Loop

Sheet2.Cells(1, col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before too and I think I found the answer.

If you are using a button to run the macro, it is likely linked to a different macro, perhaps a save as version of what you are currently working in and you might not even realize it. Try running the macro directly from VBA (F5) instead of running it with the button. My guess is that will work. You just have to reassign the macro on the button to the one you actually want to run.

Answer (score -2):

selection=selection.values

this do things at a very fast way.

Comment: Please clarify how this answers the original question?

Comment: That is an interesting way to override data in a selection with values only, but doesn't really address the asked question.