# Copy numbers (with formula inside) in other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

In `Sheet1`, I have `B10` and `C10` with a formula like:

```
=SI(B3=0;B6;SI(B6=0;B3;SI(B3<>B6;B6;B3)))
```

[image]

And with the VBA I increment the row and add my number.

[image]

But the numbers where they are the formulae is reading `#REF`.

Here is my VBA Code :

```
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Modification").Range("A10:AL10").Copy _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Données Enregistrées").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try copy/paste Value?

```
Sub CopyCol()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("B").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

[Excel VBA Copy Paste Values only( xlPasteValues )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937684/910087)

Comment: Dear,

Many Thanks for your answer.

I've tried and modified your code but it still doesn't work. There is error!


  

    Sheets("Sheet1").Row("10").Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Row("1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

And I still need to increment the row in my sheet2..

Thanks to help me))))