# excel pass data and not formula to other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to collect data from a cell from one sheet(3 Combined I) and pass it to a cell in another sheet(5 Gas I) using vba via a command button. This is what I have tried to use but it insteads copies the formula within that cell from sheet 3 Combined I?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets("3 Combined I").Range("e23").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("5 Gas I").Range("d10")

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets("5 Gas I").Range("d10").Value = Worksheets("3 Combined I").Range("e23").Value`

Comment: @Comintern, this seems an answer to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Worksheets("5 Gas I").Range("d10").value = Worksheets("3 Combined I").Range("e23").value
End Sub
```

You can also try the `PasteSpecial` method of `Range` object.
Please see [Excel VBA Copy Paste Values only( xlPasteValues )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23937262/6202343)

#### Updated

@nbayly recommands `Value2` property of `Range` object instead of `Value` property.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Worksheets("5 Gas I").Range("d10").value2 = Worksheets("3 Combined I").Range("e23").value2
End Sub
```

Reason as: [What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17359835/6202343)

Comment: worked perfectly, was expecting some complex special paste code completely overlooked the idea you could write that the cell is equal to previous one. Brilliant, thank you.

Comment: You can also try the `specialPaste` method in `Range` object.  But I prefer the most simple one as `range(xxx).value = range(yyy).value`.

Comment: I would suggest using `range(xxx).Value2 = range(yyy).Value2` instead, as this provides more consistently the appropriate answer. `.Value` has the drawback of being subject to some formatting, changing the value that you are passing (ie rounding to 2 digits if cell is formatted as currency).

Comment: @nbayly Yes, your are right.  I just checked  [http://stackoverflow.com/q/17359835/6202343](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17359835/6202343).