# formula to input a comma in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I have here 60 contacts with address. I need to put a comma in the street number after the street name like this
example:

```
12 Chatswood Court, ROBINA

12, Chatswood Court, ROBINA
```

How can I do it in excel without doing a manual because it took so long for me to do it manually ?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

If address always starts with street number then you can use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",", ",1)
```

[image]

Comment: @JonnaLuciano If that solved your problem, please mark the answer as describe in the [tour]. That's how you can say "thanks" around here.

Comment: ok. I will Can I have more question. How can I copy the text and transfer it to another sheet of excel.

Comment: @JonnaLuciano - To copy and paste there are number of solutions available like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937684/6075259), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047943/excel-vba-getting-range-from-an-inactive-sheet) and [this](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/)