# copy cell value not the formula

Tags: vba, excel

I think this is a very easy fix for those that know VBA macros well. For some reason adding `.value` at the end creates a runtime error.

Could you, please, help and let me know how to use the copy method of column B, but instead of copying the formula in the original `inputs` sheet, I could copy the value only.

```
Sub StatusPointBuild()
'
' StatusPointBuild Macro
'

'
    Dim y As Long

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status Output").Cells.ClearContents
    Worksheets("Status Template").Range("B2:DW2").Copy Worksheets("Status Output").Range("B2:DW2")

    'only copy the number of times as the count in cell A1
    y = Sheets("inputs").Range("A1").Value
    Worksheets("Status Template").Range("B3:DW3").Copy Worksheets("Status Output").Range("B3:DW3").Resize(y)
    Range("B3:DW90").Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        Worksheets("inputs").Range("B:B").Copy Worksheets("Status Output").Range("B:B")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

    Sheets("Status Output").Activate

End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937262/excel-vba-copy-paste-values-only-xlpastevalues

Comment: In particular see the answer by Robotik

Comment: thank you @JamesFaix. However, updating the copy command to         Worksheets("inputs").Columns(2).Copy
        Worksheets("Status Output").Columns(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues puts me in an infinite loop

Comment: How many rows are you dealing with and how complicated are the formulas?

Comment: @JamesFaix, it is a simple copy column from one worksheet to another and I am dealing with  24 rows, but only specifying one example in the code above. Only column B.