# Read only Values from Range and copy to Destination:Sheets("MyData"). Cells(x,y)

Tags: excel, vba, cells

I have set a range

```
Dim vWorkingRange As Range
```

I'm reading my data as:

```
Set vWorkingRange = Range(Sheets("My Sheet").Cells(RowStart,  ColStart)),Sheets("My Sheet").Cells(RowFinish, ColFinish))
```

This is a single column of data. Now I want to paste the values

```
vWorkingRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("My Sheet").Cells(myRow,myCol)
```

I'd like to read the values only from the source range as it may have a formula.  But when I paste to my destination sheet I get the formula and not the value.

I cant seem to locate how to do this.

Comment: if it is a single column then won't both column references be the same i.e. both colStart  or both ColFinish?

Comment: you want paste special method which means your paste will be on a different line from the copy. Paste as values. macro recorder will capture this if you perform the actions.

Comment: Possible duplicate.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937262/excel-vba-copy-paste-values-only-xlpastevalues

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this...

```
vWorkingRange.Copy
Sheets("My Sheet").Cells(myRow, myCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: That did not work, I get a Compile Error  Expected: End of statement message

Comment: Check your code. Do you have a `With / End With` block in your code? It seems you forgot to include `End With`.

Answer (score 0):

a faster, and more reliable code could be:

```
With Sheets("My Sheet") ' reference wanted sheet
    With Range(.Cells(RowStart, ColStart), .Cells(RowFinish, ColFinish)) ' reference referenced sheet range
        .Parent.Cells(myRow, myCol).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value 'copy referenced range values only and paste them starting from referenced sheet cells(myRow, myCol)
    End With
End With
```

Comment: This looks good however I'm only reading on value and not the full range back to the parent sheet.

I could however maybe set up a loop and read it cell by cell, seems a bit over kill however.

Comment: I understand you only get one cell pasted but that's not what's happening in my test. Please, check carefully your actual values of `RowStart, ColStart, RowFinish, ColFinish, myRow, myCol` before the last statements gets executed (setp through your code and use Immediate Window)