# If, Then, With Paste Only Values

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that works perfectly except for I can not seem to paste only values of the copied cell. How would I tell this code to only paste values and not merely copy and paste the cell. I have tried Google, Stack etc with no luck every variation of paste special I try fails! Thanks!

```
Sheets("AAAA").Select

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
With Sheets("AAAA")
    LR = .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LR
       With .Range("G" & i)
            If .Cells.Value = "NO MATCH" Then
                With Sheets("BBBB")
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8).Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Havbe you tried googling "paste values"? (or checking this site)

Comment: No need to down vote... as I said I have googled and searched for the proper syntax to paste values only in my code. I have also seen this linked question which covers basic paste values code, as I said I have searched for a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the `PasteSpecial` method? Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30374158/194717

Comment: You could also consider assigning the values directly, instead of using clipboard: `range("A1").value2 = range("B1").value2` assigns whatever value is in cell B1 to A1 (remember to qualify workbook and worksheet name).

Comment: Thanks for the comments and assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with nested `With` statements. Maybe fully qualify the second sheet in the inner `With`.

That said, you can remove the copy altogether and swop it round into an assignment using `.Text` property of range (cell) to give value only e.g.

```
 .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text
```

Better still use `.Value2`

```
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value2
```

It preserves more formats and is more resilient.

Comment: Thanks for this. I see my error in how I was writing this out. Thanks!

Comment: Why use `.Text`? It's  slower, limited to a single cell, and may give unexpected results depending on the cell format.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks. Wasn't thinking properly.