# Copying rows from sheets and paste in one master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 247 sheets in an Excel file and I need to copy the rows from each sheet and paste in one "Master" sheet. Each sheet has between 100 and 400 rows.
For some reason the code I have is omitting most of the sheets and seems to work and copy only few sheets.

```
Sub CleanV2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim finalRow As Long
Dim H As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'''''''''Paste to Analysis'''''
    
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "ImportCommand" And ws.Name <> "Analysis" And ws.Name <> "Cities" Then
ws.Select

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:H" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Analysis").Select
 
 
  finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
H = finalRow + 1
 'Sheets("MasterData").Select
Sheets("Analysis").Range("$A$" & H).Select
On Error Resume Next
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
On Error Resume Next

End If
Next
''''''Finish paste'''''

End Sub
```

Any help why why code is not copying and pasting each sheet. It seems code is copying each sheet but the paste is not working as needed.

Thank you

Comment: I'd start with removing the `On Error Resume Next`, [avoiding Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), and [transferring the value directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528000/vba-paste-as-values-how-to).

Comment: Hello - Can you please clarify "avoiding Select, and transferring the value directly" ?

Comment: Did you click the hyperlinks? Basically, avoid using `Select` and `Selection`, and transfer the `.Value` of the range directly instead of using `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`.

Comment: Oh havent checked the hyperlinks. Let me see./

Comment: I started with removing "On Error Resume Next" the code runs okay but then stops with this error: "Overflow"

Comment: `Dim H As Long`