# Insert calculated values instead of formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i have the following code, where i paste a formula to a range of cells.
the problem is, that is slows down my excel sheet massively.
how can i only add the calculated values instead of the formula itself?

```
 Set rng = Range("C4") 'select cell where first value of the filtered values is

   Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=countif(C[-3]:C[-3] ,R[]C[-1])"
    Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).Offset(, 1).Copy
    Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba - not going to fix your question but it will improve your code.

Comment: And the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937262/excel-vba-copy-paste-values-only-xlpastevalues will fix your question.

Comment: thank you, but regarding your first comment : if i change it to a range, then i dont know how to adapt my 3rd line of code

Comment: Easy in your case: delete the first line and replace `Selection` with `Range("c4")` everywhwere.  Or, better, declare a `Range` variable, assign `Range("c4")` to it and use that.

Comment: thx. that worked. do you have a different solution for the pastespecial xlpastevalues thing?  is extremely slow for me. i adapted my question

Comment: nevermind. find a solution 
Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).Offset(, 1).Value = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).Offset(, 1).Value