# Copy and paste values only after filtering data in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I’m new in VBA and I’m trying to copy and paste filtering data into another sheet. When I launch my code, nothing happens, no error messages either.

**Input Sheet "DONNEE DRAFT" Columns K and L :**

|  | BU (K) | AL (L) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FRQ40 | ALPYIP |
| 2 | FRXK0 | ALPAJW |
| 3 | FRRZ0 | ALPK29 |
| 4 | FR500 | ALPAGD |
| 5 | FR500 | ALPH51 |
| 6 | FR040 | ALPH51 |
| 7 | etc... | etc... |

Note: data in Column K -> VlookUp formula

I'm adding a filter in this table > filtering in BU (Columns K) : "FR500"
I copy the column K and L then past into another sheet:

In Columns A :BU "FR500" and in C :AL linked to FR500). In the example bellow it's what we have in line 6 and 7 (It won't start at this specified row always).

**Outpout Expect in Sheet "IML" :**

|  | BU (A) | BU AFF (B) | AL (C) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | data | other data | data |
| 2 | data | other data | data |
| 3 | data | other data | data |
| 4 | data | other data | data |
| 5 | data | other data | data |
| 6 | FR500 | other data | ALPH51 |
| 7 | FR500 | other data | ALPAGD |

Here the code (I tried only to copy/paste "BU"):

```
    Dim FR500 As Range
    Dim LastRow As Double
    Dim LastRow2 As Double
    
    LastRow = Sheets("DONNEE DRAFT").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last row
    LastRow2 = Sheets("IML").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Set FR500 = Sheets("DONNEE DRAFT").Range("K1").CurrentRegion
    Sheets("DONNEE DRAFT").AutoFilterMode = False 'turning off all filter
    FR500.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="FR500" 'filtering data

    Sheets("DONNEE DRAFT").Range("K" & LastRow).Copy
    Sheets("IML").Range("A" & LastRow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Excel does not know in which sheet `Range("K" & LastRow).Copy` is. Specify a sheet for that range.

Comment: HI @Pᴇʜ, thanks for your help. I specified the "DONNE DRAFT" sheet. `Sheet("DONNEE DRAFT").Range("K" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("IML").Range("A" & LastRow2)`. But in my input, in column K it's a formula (Vlookup), how do I copy/paste  only the values (I edit my question to specify this point)

Comment: Solution is: Do some research, that was asked be fore: [Copy Paste Values only( xlPasteValues )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937262/copy-paste-values-only-xlpastevalues)

Comment: ok, I did some research before and try, it didn't work, that's why I post here. But thank you anyway

Comment: I don't see in your code that you have tried what I posted as a link.

Comment: I apply this code:  `Sheets("DONNEE DRAFT").Range("K" & LastRow).Copy
    Sheets("IML").Range("A" & LastRow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. But it's the same, nothing is pasted

Comment: `Lastrow` is `Sheets("DONNEE DRAFT").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` so you are choosing 1 row **below** last one with data. That means an **empty** cell. Then you copy/paste that empty cell with `Sheets("DONNEE DRAFT").Range("K" & LastRow).Copy` Also, Notice you copy a single one, not a range of several cells.

Comment: Also declare `LastRow` and `LastRow2` as `Long`. The type `Double` is a decimal value but row numbers are integer numbers, ther exists no row `2.3` for example. This might cause some issues (or not, but fix it). Note that if you want to copy the filtered data only you need to use something like `Sheets("DONNEE DRAFT").Range("K1:K" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`